# 010 Editor: create dynamic names

Tags: templates, editor, binaryfiles

I'm trying to create a binary template with 010 Editor, and I'm trying to create some dynamic names, like this:

```
local int x;
local string track;

typedef struct {
    uchar unk1 <name="Unused">;
    
    for(x=1; x<4; x++) {
        SPrintf( track, "Track %d", x );
        STRUCT1_entry Trackxx <name=track>;
    }

    uchar filler[248];
} STRUCT1;
```

I would expect to have, as a result, the creation of 3 STRUCT1_entry named:

- Track 1
- Track 2
- Track 3

but what I get is different

- Track 3
- Track 3
- Track 3

It seems that the name only gets the last value assigned. Do you know what I am missing here?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If one variable name is defined in loop, or directly one after another, it'll be merged as an array: https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/manual/ArraysDuplicates.htm

In this example the `Trackxx` is an array of `STRUCT1_entry` type, and you're changing the name of the whole array.

You can however set a custom string which will be displayed in the "Value" row of the result table: https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/manual/CustomVariables.htm

```
for(x=1; x<4; x++) {
    SPrintf( track, "Track %d", x );
    STRUCT1_entry Trackxx <read=track>;
}
```

or

```
for(x=1; x<4; x++) {
    STRUCT1_entry Trackxx <read=Str("Track %d", x)>;
}
```